# Android VideoView using rtsp only start when video stream is available

Tags: android, stream, android-videoview, rtsp

I am attempting to display video using a VideoView only when the rtsp video stream is available. I see many examples out there where people use a button to start the VideoView, but nothing on how to listen for the incoming stream.

```
video_stream.setVideoPath("rtsp://MY_IP/stream");
    video_stream.requestFocus();
    video_stream.start();
```

If I try to execute this before there is a stream, I get "can't play this video". If I start the stream before hand, it functions normally.

Comment: Presumably, you would have to find some RTSP client code that you can use directly to determine if the stream is available. Then, when it is, start using the `VideoView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup a onErrorListener, setup an onCompleteListener, start the stream as I did above.

```
video_stream.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp,int what, int extra) {video_stream.setVideoPath("rtsp://IP/stream");
                                video_stream.requestFocus();
                                video_stream.start();}
    });video_stream.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            video_stream.setVideoPath("rtsp://IP/stream");
            video_stream.requestFocus();
            video_stream.start();

        }
    });video_stream.setVideoPath("rtsp://IP/stream");
    video_stream.requestFocus();
    video_stream.start();
```

Every time we get an error, we try to reconnect. If the stream ends, we try to reconnect right away.